# How to integrate Beam SQL windowing query with KafkaIO?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-beam, beam-sql

First, we have a kafka input source in JSON format:

```
{"event_time": "2020-08-23 18:36:10", "word": "apple", "cnt": 1}
{"event_time": "2020-08-23 18:36:20", "word": "banana", "cnt": 1}
{"event_time": "2020-08-23 18:37:30", "word": "apple", "cnt": 2}
{"event_time": "2020-08-23 18:37:40", "word": "apple", "cnt": 1}
... ...
```

What I'm trying to do is to aggregate the sum of the count of each word by every minute:

```
+---------+----------+---------------------+
| word    | SUM(cnt) |   window_start      |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
| apple   |    1     | 2020-08-23 18:36:00 |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
| banana  |    1     | 2020-08-23 18:36:00 |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
| apple   |    3     | 2020-08-23 18:37:00 |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
```

So this case would be perfectly fit the following Beam SQL statement:

```
SELECT word, SUM(cnt), TUMBLE_START(event_time, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE) as window_start
FROM t_count_stats
GROUP BY word, TUMBLE(event_time, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE)
```

And below is my current working code using Beam's Java SDK to execute this streaming SQL query:

```
import avro.shaded.com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.SqlTransform;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.Schema;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SimpleFunction;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class KafkaBeamSqlTest {

    private static DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create pipeline
        PipelineOptions kafkaOption = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)
                .withoutStrictParsing()
                .as(PipelineOptions.class);
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(kafkaOption);

        // create kafka IO
        KafkaIO.Read<String, String> kafkaRead =
                KafkaIO.<String, String>read()
                        .withBootstrapServers("127.0.0.1:9092")
                        .withTopic("beamKafkaTest")
                        .withConsumerConfigUpdates(ImmutableMap.of("group.id", "client-1"))
                        .withReadCommitted()
                        .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                        .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                        .commitOffsetsInFinalize();

        // read from kafka
        PCollection<KV<String, String>> messages = pipeline.apply(kafkaRead.withoutMetadata());

        // build input schema
        Schema inputSchema = Schema.builder()
                .addStringField("word")
                .addDateTimeField("event_time")
                .addInt32Field("cnt")
                .build();

        // convert kafka message to Row
        PCollection<Row> rows = messages.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, String>, Row>(){
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                String jsonData = c.element().getValue();

                // parse json
                JSONObject jsonObject = JSON.parseObject(jsonData);

                // build row
                List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(jsonObject.get("word"));
                list.add(dtf.parseDateTime((String) jsonObject.get("event_time")));
                list.add(jsonObject.get("cnt"));
                Row row = Row.withSchema(inputSchema)
                        .addValues(list)
                        .build();

                System.out.println(row);

                // emit row
                c.output(row);
            }
        }))
                .setRowSchema(inputSchema);

        // sql query
        PCollection<Row> result = PCollectionTuple.of(new TupleTag<>("t_count_stats"), rows)
                .apply(
                        SqlTransform.query(
                                "SELECT word, SUM(cnt), TUMBLE_START(event_time, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE) as window_start\n" +
                                "FROM t_count_stats\n" +
                                "GROUP BY word, TUMBLE(event_time, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE)"
                        )
                );

        // sink results back to another kafka topic
        result.apply(MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<Row, KV<String, String>>() {
            @Override
            public KV<String, String> apply(Row input) {

                System.out.println("result: " + input.getValues());

                return KV.of(input.getValue("word"), "result=" + input.getValues());
            }
        }))
                .apply(KafkaIO.<String, String>write()
                        .withBootstrapServers("127.0.0.1:9092")
                        .withTopic("beamPrint")
                        .withKeySerializer(StringSerializer.class)
                        .withValueSerializer(StringSerializer.class));

        // run
        pipeline.run();
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I run this code and feed some messages into Kafka, there's no exception throwing out and it has received some messages from Kafka, but I cannot see it trigger the process for the windowing aggregation. And there's no result coming out as expected (like the table I shown before).

So does Beam SQL currently support the window syntax on unbounded Kafka input source? If it does, what's wrong with my current code? How can I debug and fix it? And is there any code example that integrates Beam SQL with KafkaIO?

Please help me! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was answered at https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/rea75c0eb665f90b8483e64bee96740ebb01942c606f065066c2ecc56%40%3Cuser.beam.apache.org%3E